# How to keep distinct values of x-axis in matplotlib pyplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a list containing 2000 values which are years in the range of 2006-2017. I want to use this values in the x-axis in my plot. How can I keep distinct year values removing duplicates. Here is an example:

```
dates = ['2006', '2006', '2006', '2007', '2007', '2007', '2008', '2008', '2008']
x = np.arange(len(dates))
plt.xticks(x, dates)
y = [0.523,0.512,0.599,0.595,0.555,0.66,0.99,0.52,0.52]

plt.plot(y)
plt.axhline(0, color='black')
plt.legend(['ORG'], loc='best', prop={'size': 15})

plt.show()
```

In the plot, how can I remove duplicate values and keep only one values from each distinct year?

[image]

EDIT:
The years appearing in the "dates" list have been extracted from dates. i.e. 2006-01-25, 2006-01-26, 2006-01-27, 2006-01-28 ...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of the issue. Also clearly state the problem: In how far is the result you get not what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data representation in the question does not seem too reasonable. I would expect to have the same year on the same x axis position, not spread over several of them. Hence plotting the data against the date would be a useful option.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = ['2006', '2006', '2006', '2007', '2007', '2007', '2008', '2008', '2008']

y = [0.523,0.512,0.599,0.595,0.555,0.66,0.99,0.52,0.52]

plt.plot(dates, y, marker="o", ls="")

plt.axhline(0, color='black')
plt.legend(['ORG'], loc='best', prop={'size': 15})

plt.show()
```

[image]

If instead the dates are real dates, keep them as dates.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(3)

start = datetime.datetime(2006,1,1)
dates = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 2000)]

y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(2000))+70

plt.plot(dates, y)

plt.axhline(0, color='black')
plt.legend(['ORG'], loc='best', prop={'size': 15})

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer and sorry for the missing info. Please see the edit.

Comment: Not sure what the edit tells me. If you want to plot the date including the day, why do you truncate it?

Comment: Since I have thousands of dates, I just wanted to extract years and show distinct years only once.

Comment: I guess you ran into an [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info). Of course you need to plot the complete dates then. I updated the answer.